# Invalid Block Type

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I keep getting the same error in the exception.log. Can somebody help me on how to fix this.
Thanks.

```
2015-06-17T11:11:17+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'category.produc...')
#3 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'category.produc...')
#4 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/community/Magehouse/Slider/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(99): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magehouse_Slider_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /is/htdocs/wp11168183_A0ZPKHKDV8/www/ruffstore19/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Comment: Have a look where you add blocks with a name of "category.products" somewhere in your layout xml and update your answer with the corresponding xml.

Comment: Could also be something like <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml"> with a wrong declaration of type.

Comment: Ok i found it in Store view one:

catalog.xml
        <reference name="content">
         <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
...

Comment: and in local.xml
<!-- Custom static blocks -->
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="content">
                <block name="category.products">
                        <block type="cms/block" name="products_collection_top">
                                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>products_collection_top</block_id></action>
                        </block>

Comment: @Stefan. It's the second one `<block name="category.products">` should be `<reference name="category.products">`

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you have something like this in your layout files

```
 <block name="category.products"....
```

that should be

```
 <reference name="category.products"....
```

Comment: What he said. ;)

Comment: Ok I changed in local.xml
`<block name="category.products">` to `<reference name="category.products">`

Comment: @Stefan. And does it fixes the problem?

Comment: I just checked, it does fix the problem which came in english with invalid block. But i had the same with a german error "Ungültiger Block". I thought this might fix both at the same time. Any ideas how to fix the second one which is german? Thanks for the great and fast help anyway.

Comment: ... Mage::throwException('Ung??ltiger Blo...')

Comment: If you still see this in the german website it means there is an other similar problem that reproduces only on the german store view. I have no idea what that might be. Search for something similar, that gets loaded maybe only on the german website.

Comment: Just figures out by changing the block to reference in local.xml it damages the design of the template.